# Consuming messages one by one with RabbitMQ and Camel

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, throttling, consumer

I have a RabbitMQ broker and a Camel Java application that consumes the messages. The consumer process one message in ca. 1 second. I produce 10'000 messages; this is almost instanteneous. Immediately the RabbitMQ console reports that the queue contains no more that ca. 7'000 messages. This is an issue for me, because if the consumer fails, 3'000 messages or so are lost.

I tried several options:

- stream caching: `camelContext.setStreamCaching(false);`  // or `true`
- throttling: `from(queue).throttle(1)`
- prefetch: `from(rabbitmq:exchange&queue=q&prefetchEnabled=true&prefetchCount=1&prefetchGlobal=false&prefetchSize=0`

all to no avail. I never observe a regular decrese (10'000, then 9'999, 9'998, etc) in the number of messages in the queue. It is quite the opposite: I can always see that messages get out of the queue in large chunks (typically 3'000 messages), although the consumer actually processes them slowly.

How can I consume the messages one by one?

Comment: I ended up stopping to use Camel. I switched to Spring RabbitMQ, which is slightly more verbose but so much easier!

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be a bit too late for you but I have also been battling the same issue and I finally found a solution to make the Camel RabbitMq component consume messages one by one.

You just set the `autoAck` property to `false`.

Below I have a sample of the whole route definition:

```html
rabbitmq:your-exchange?routingKey=rtkey&queue=qname&autoDelete=false&durable=true&guaranteedDeliveries=true&threadPoolSize=1&autoAck=false
```

Then the important part is just:

```
guaranteedDeliveries=true&threadPoolSize=1&autoAck=false
```

The `threadPoolSize` and `guaranteedDeliveries` properties are not necessary to achieve what you want, I am just putting them here for completeness' sake.

Here is a [link to the documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.13.x/rabbitmq-component.html#_endpoint_query_option_autoAck)

Answer (score 0):

Run this route in a transaction. That way a failed consumer will end up with rollback of the messages onto the queue.